# Why Won't Komodo 6 Run or Debug Python 3 Code?

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, komodo

**My problem:**

I try to debug some python 3 code.  Komodo gives me this error message:

"Komodo does not support execution of Python3 files through the debugger subsystem, please use a run command in the toolbox to process this file."

then when I run 'run,' it gives me this error:

"'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

ActiveState says that Komodo 6 supports python 3:

"Komodo 6 fully supports Python 3 (debugging, code intelligence"

http://community.activestate.com/komodo-60-features

what to do, what to do?

**My stuff:**

Komodo IDE, version 6.0.0-beta3, build 54627, platform win32-x86

ActivePython-3.1.1.2-win64-x64-nopywin32

Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Komodo 6 supports Python 3 properly. The version you used only supported the code intelligence (nice formatting), but not the execution/debugging.